# how to fix the code of navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I spend 6 hours to solve the problem, but it still be like that.... I want to push my LoginController to MainViewController, and then, the complier pop out this red dot, it said that Arguement passed to call that takes no arguements. I hope everyone can do me a faver~~~~[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri2YL.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, post the exact error message and the code as text that is search-able and paste-able.

Comment: It's fairly clear from the error message. The function you are calling "instantiateInitialViewController" takes no input parameters. Look st the docs.

Comment: Sorry luk2303, I don't know what you said... because I post the screenshots involve message error.

Comment: yes, post both code and error message as text, NOT as screenshot.

Comment: THANKS luk2303. I'll follow the rule here^^ sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using instantiate**View**Controller:

```
let mainViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController
```

Also I think its better to use if let in the case the call fails

```
if let mainViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? DetailViewController {
}
```

Comment: thanks, bro. you help me a lot.  Actually, I have another question.... . I set different file with different storyboard. When I type above the code, the console said that the storyboard can't find the MainViewController. Can you teach me why?thx^^

Comment: Its better to create a new question in case i cant solve it brother, wait is this not solved?

Comment: Anyways, I think it could be because storyboard only works only if you created the MainViewController in Main.storyboard with an identifier: "MainViewController". 

If you created your MainViewController.swift programmatically, try this: 

let mvc = MainViewController()
self.navigationController?pushViewController(mvc, animated: true)

Comment: I am not a pro at iOS, so thats why I thought making a question might be better incase I'm wrong.

Comment: you solve well, bro. get you thumb up! you're so awesome here^^ it's my first time to learn how to code, it's really interesting,  and I'm so glad here make lots of friends.

Comment: So try not using the self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController and just create it using let mvc = MainViewController()... etc